# Ghostscript PDF TO Image conversion logs message

Tags: node.js, ghostscript

I am using GS to convert PDF To Image and crop it to margin using Sharp Library.

I am passing the converted PDF Image to sharp as buffer.

the PDF is logging something after conversion:

`**** The file was produced by: **** >>>> Qt 4.8.7; modified using iText� 5.2.1 �2000-2012 1T3XT BVBA <<<<`

as i am using `STDOUT` for output in GS the Above messsage is passed to the stdout and making the buffer corrupt for `Sharp`

How can i ignore such messages ?

How to not include those console messages in stdout ?